# Map as parameter for all fields for EJB backend calls

Tags: java, api, rest, ejb

I am designing backend EJB calls to be called by REST api.
Example for EJB calls;
 
Get all Systems

`getSystems(String systemId)`

Now I know that i would get system id to get all systems. 
There is a possibility of retrieving them by some another unique id as well

`getSystemsByOtherId(String otherId)`

There is requirement that there could be sort parameter passed in

`getSystems(String systemId, String sort_by, String sort_how)`

Would it be better to have something like Map as param and have it passed in with every information

`getSystems(Map criteria)`

So the key- value pair for Map would have systemId, otherId, sort_by, sort_how and more if needed in future. Or is it better to follow other approach to have unique methods for different params. Or if there is some other better approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use an object? something like `getSystems(Criteria criteria)`, the class `Criteria` could change without changing you EJB signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is a little cumbersome, in case you want to add or remove parameters you'd have to modify the signature of your EJB every time, the map solution is a little dirty since you'd have to keep track of your parameters names at runtime and if you want to use parameters of a type other than `String` you'd lose typing info at runtime as well.

This is how I would do it, define a class that encapsulates your parameters:

```
public class Criteria {
  private String systemId;
  private String otherId;
  private String sortBy;
  private String sortHow;
         .
         .
         .
}
```

and in your EJB,

```
getSystem(Criteria criteria)
```